# How to make dropdown toggle working with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, toggle, sidebar

I am currently coding my very first sidebar with toggle function for submenues. I tried to use W3schools tut but I just can't get it running. When i click the buttons within the sidebar the submenues won't appear.

The console here tells me that "toogle" is undefined. I guess something is wrong with the javascript code.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

```js
//* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its dropdown content - This allows the user to have multiple dropdowns without any conflict */
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.subbar.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

body {
    line-height:1;
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section {
    display:block;
}

nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes:none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content:none;
}

a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
ins {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
mark {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
}

del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

abbr[title], dfn[title] {
    border-bottom:1px dotted;
    cursor:help;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}

/* change border colour to suit your needs */
hr {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;
    border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
}

input, select {
    vertical-align:middle;
}

/************************************Main code*********************************************/

/* Landing Page */

body {
  background-image: image();
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
position: relative;
text-align: center;
color: red;
}

.dasocc {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 65px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* Dashboard */
/* Toggle Styles */

#viewport {
  padding-left: 250px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 0;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

#sidebar {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #5BB281;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#sidebar header {
  background-color: #5BB281;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: roboto; sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 52px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#sidebar header a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar header a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}

#sidebar .nav a{
  background: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: -1;
}

#sidebar .nav img{
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#sidebar .nav li{
  padding-top: 10px;

}

#sidebar .nav a:hover{
  background: none;
  color: #8A0094;
}

#subbar .team {
font-size: 10px;
font-family: roboto; sans-serif;
padding-left: 50px;
}

#subbar {
  display: none
}

.button {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width:100%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.button:hover {
color: #8A0094;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <title>dasocc</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="viewport">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar">
      <header>
        <a href="#">dasocc</a>
      </header>
      <ul class="nav">
          <button class="button"><img src="images/germany.png">1. Bundesliga</button>
        <div id="subbar">
          <li>
          <a class="team">FC Bayern München</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a class="team">Borussia Dortmund</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a class="team">Bayer Leverkusen</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a class="team">RB Leipzig</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a class="team">VfL Wolfsburg</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a class="team">SC Freiburg</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a class="team">Eintracht Frankfurt</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a class="team">Borussia M. Gladbach</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a class="team">FC Schalke 04</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a class="team">TSG Hoffenheim</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a class="team">1. FC Union Berlin</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a class="team">Fortuna Düsseldorf</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a class="team">Werder Bremen</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a class="team">1. FC Köln</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a class="team">SC Paderborn</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a class="team">FC Augsburg</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a class="team">Hertha BSC Berlin</a>
          </li>
        </div>
        <li>
          <button class="button"><img src="images/england.png" alt="">Premier League</button>
        </li>
        <div id="subbar">
          <li>
          <a class="team">FC Bayern München</a>
          </li>
        <li>
        </div>
        <li>
          <button class="button"><img src="images/france.png" alt="">Ligue One</button>
        </li>
        <div id="subbar">
          <li>
          <a class="team">FC Bayern München</a>
          </li>
        <li>
        </div>
        <li>
          <button class="button"><img src="images/spain.png" alt="">La Liga</button>
        </li>
        <div id="subbar">
          <li>
          <a class="team">FC Bayern München</a>
          </li>
        <li>
        </div>
        <li>
          <button class="button"><img src="images/italy.png">Serie A</button>
        </li>
        <div id="subbar">
          <li>
          <a class="team">FC Bayern München</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Content -->


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: MANY errors. 1: Duplicate IDs, 2 There is no subbar that is accessible by this.subbar - you would need something like `this.closest("someCommonSelector").querySelector(".subbar")` Your HTML is invalid anyway. Please run it through a validator. W3Schools is a poor resource too

Comment: Correct the HTML, have ULs instead of DIV and put the UL directly after the button,. Then you can do `for (let i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    dropdownContent.classList.toggle("active");
  });
}` where active is an actual class that has `display:block;`

Comment: Alternatively delegate the click to the parent. Then no need to loop. Just check the `event.target.matches(".button")`

Answer (score 0):

Couln't solve it via js but instead found a css hover work-around.

Nevertheless thank you for yor input. Helped me a lot to improve my understanding.